# Spring tool suite java perspective shows blank

Tags: java, eclipse

This keeps happening to me very often these days.

I can't see any of my classes in my <kbd>**Java perspective**</kbd> unless I change perspective to say debug/spring. The workspace is completely gray. When I do `window -->show view --> package explorer`, nothing shows up either.

I have no clue what is causing this. I would really appreciate your help here.

Screenshot attached.

[image]

Comment: You might try resetting the perspective. Check out [Resetting Perspectives](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-9j.htm)

Comment: please post the version of eclipse/STS that you are using

Comment: i would start checking error logs.

Comment: @CPU 100 - I am using spring sts.

Comment: @rickygrimes then post the version of STS and also update the title of this question to be STS not eclipse...even though STS is the base on eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try Window/Reset perspective.
this should restore the default settings of current perspective.

Comment: By "Rest" do you mean "Reset"?

Comment: Yes, reset worked. I wouldn't have caught that. Thanks so much.

Comment: Yes, I mean "reset". Sorry for misspelling.